# UnauthorizedAccessException in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get the `device_id` in Windows Phone 8. I tried doing this:

```
byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
string DeviceIDAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);
```

and this:

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId").ToString();
```

Both resulted in the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>        Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 
>       (E_ACCESSDENIED))

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add required capabilities in your App manifest file. Particularly, try to add this capability :

```
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE
```

For reference :

- [MSDN : How to modify the app manifest file for Windows Phone
  8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_pagecap)
- [MSDN : App capabilities and hardware requirements for Windows Phone
  8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think You must have forgot to add Capability. `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE` should be checked in WMAppMenifest.xml